# App Crash once replace Fragment for scoped ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, scope, android-viewmodel, koin

**Bug**

I was found an issue when I try to open fragment and then replace with the same fragment.
In our prod application, it's a popular case.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Definition without any InstanceContext - [type:Scope,scope:'com.abc.view.fragment.BrowseTaskFragment', primary_type:'com.abc.viewModel.BrowseTaskVM']
        at org.koin.core.definition.BeanDefinition.resolveInstance(BeanDefinition.kt:72)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:141)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:131)
        at com.abc.view.fragment.BrowseTaskFragment$$special$$inlined$inject$1.invoke(Scope.kt:274)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at com.abc.view.fragment.BrowseTaskFragment.getMViewModel(Unknown Source:25)
        at com.abc.view.fragment.BrowseTaskFragment.getMViewModel(BrowseTaskFragment.kt:37)
        at com.abc.base.BaseFragment.performViewModelBinding(BaseFragment.kt:55)
        at com.abc.base.BaseFragment.onViewCreated(BaseFragment.kt:31)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1471)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

**Steps to reproduce the behavior:**

- I have BottomNavigationView once I tap on existing fragment which is visible, getting above crash.

**Koin version: 2.0.1**

**Module**

```
val viewModelModule = module {
     scope(named<BrowseTaskFragment>()) {
        scoped { BrowseTaskVM() }
      }
    }
```

**Application class**

```
startKoin {
            androidContext(this@AbcApplication)
            modules(listOf(appModule, stateModule, apiModule, viewModelModule))
        }
```

Comment: can you add your module ?

Comment: @jinsjoseph : question updated.

Comment: @jinsjoseph : Check updated answer.

Comment: @jinsjoseph No need context as parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can do this by create scope. 
>   First in your module class create scope by named koin method

```
val viewModelModule = module {
 scope(named<BrowseTaskFragment>()) {
   scoped { BrowseTaskVM() }
  }
}
```

> Second in your fragment

```
private val viewModelScope = getKoin().getOrCreateScope("Scope1",named<BrowseTaskFragment>())
private val browseTaskVM: BrowseTaskVM= viewModelScope.get()
```

> Last in an onDestoy method close your scope.

```
 override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    viewModelScope.close()
}
```

Comment: Solve this issue after applying your solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

define in application class like this

```
  startKoin {
           androidContext(this@ApplicationContext)
        // your modules
        modules(listOf(your modules))
    }
```

and pass context in you modules